# Facebook "Like" and "Share" buttons on a website, which is better?

Tags: facebook, web, seo, social-networking

I was wondering, What's the difference between users "liking" a page and users "sharing" it.
For example let's say I have a news website with lots of articles. Should i have a "Like" button on the homepage and a "Share" button on each individual article? Or maybe the opposite is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't recommend using the [Share button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share), instead using the [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like). This is what Facebook says about the Like Button.

> The Like button lets a user share your
>   content with friends on Facebook. When
>   the user clicks the Like button on
>   your site, a story appears in the
>   user's friends' News Feed with a link
>   back to your website.

More info and tutorial are available from the link above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Why Facebook recommends using the Like button (***beware, sarcasm inside***) :

- [It gives them more information on users.](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4115/4829376847_303681ee99_z.jpg)
- Everything is controlled by them (via iFrame or hosted javascript), which can be nice (widget is updating live !) (*control* is the key word here)
- [It's easy to implement](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

Why **you shouldn't use the Like one** anyway :

- [Its security is pretty bad](http://arnab.org/blog/reputation-misrepresentation) (ie : spam, hijacking, user tracking -paranoia addict-, etc.)
- [Users may want to *like* the page (or product, or whatever) but not sharing it on their page.](http://arnab.org/blog/deceiving-users-facebook-button)
- It's easy to implement the share button, or even a custom one anyway.

Answer (score 1):

an important differentiator is performance;

a share-link does not not make any request to facebook (or any other site) unless clicked, while the like-widget makes requests to facebook (hence the privacy issue Chouchenos rightfully mentions).

this indeed means that a page with the share-link will load faster than the same page with the fb like-widget.